# Android Bluetooth Discovery does not log anything

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, device

I have been working on an app which needs to find some discoverable Bluetooth devices. I have followed guides and looked at answers on here and followed. However I cannot seem to get the phone to start scanning.

Here is the full activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView scanningText;
    private ListView scanningListView;
    private Button scanningButton;
    boolean scanComplete;
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        scanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanningButton);
        scanningText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanningText);
        scanningListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scanningList);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            scanningText.setText("Your device does not support Bluetooth, Sorry!");
        }

        else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            scanningText.setText("You need to enable bluetooth to use this app..");
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }


        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


        scanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scanningText.setText("Scanning...");
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                scanningListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
            }
            else {
                Log.i("BT", "none"+ "");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

When I check the android log console, there are no logs.

Thanks

Update:

I have moved startDiscovery to the onclick listener.

```
   Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            }
            Log.i("found", pairedDevices + "");
        }
```

The following check takes place when i press the scan button. I am told the device is not discovering by the toast.

```
 scanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            scanningText.setText("Scanning...");
            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "discovering", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not discovering", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Entire Log:

```
06-14 14:50:13.356 25211-25211/? E/Zygote: v2
06-14 14:50:13.356 25211-25211/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10319
06-14 14:50:13.356 25211-25211/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
06-14 14:50:13.357 25211-25211/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
06-14 14:50:13.361 25211-25211/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[1],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 SPD:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0006 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005, [-1 -1 0 1 0 1]
06-14 14:50:13.362 25211-25211/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp 
06-14 14:50:13.365 25211-25211/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-14 14:50:13.408 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp-2/lib/arm64
06-14 14:50:13.417 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp, real application class is null.
06-14 14:50:13.607 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp-2/lib/arm64
06-14 14:50:13.688 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-14 14:50:13.770 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/found: [C1:20:21:40:9C:65, 8C:C8:CD:BB:95:28, C9:50:76:7B:89:F2, 54:53:ED:A3:B1:70, 88:A3:F2:BE:DE:42, C4:73:1E:02:1F:6B, E4:04:39:29:74:E6]
06-14 14:50:13.826 25211-25250/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-14 14:50:13.880 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
06-14 14:50:22.465 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
06-14 14:50:22.465 25211-25211/com.smartscan.app.smartscanapp E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Comment: May be worth adding I do have the manifest permissions in and have bluetooth enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding those permissions in the manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Also, it's always recommended to ask the user for permissions, so here you go :

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by adding logs at every steps.

```
Log.i("TAG", "Message")
```

Does your manifest file contains the appropriate permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Next, it seems like you do not check if the bluetooth is enabled on the device. You should use an intent to do so.

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);  
        startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH);
    }
```

Comment: 1) Okay, 2) Yes 3) I have had that before and it makes no difference. I added it in again and no change. My Bluetooth is enabled.

Comment: Alright, regarding the logs. Do you have any output in the Android Monitor?

Comment: I added the code below and got a correct log showing 8 previously connected devices.

Comment: I also added a log just under the onRecieve method and above the string action. This was not logged. The onrecieve method therefore is not starting.

Comment: mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() is called? Try adding a log before calling it.

Also, try changing "registerReceiver" for this line :
        
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

Comment: Yes it is called on the button click. I added a log under this click which outputs something. The startDiscovery looks like it isn't doing anything. Will try your suggestions now..

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Oh right. I forgot about this. I had to add this to my code to make the bluetooth discovery work on android 6.0 +.

`if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
}`

Comment: Please look at the update, I have found out through toasts and a few checks that my deice is not discovering. I will try your suggestion now S.L.R I am very certain that the problem lies with permissions somewhere...

Comment: Try adding those : 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Yes! That is it. So now it comes up asking for the permission which is what I knew i was lacking. You should post that as an answer or something as I feel like a lot of people may come across something like this. Thanks :)

Comment: I added the answer.